# How do you read JavaDoc?

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc

What tools/websites do you use to read JavaDocs?

I currently use Firefox with 20+ tabs open when working on a J2EE project to have all the documentation available which is not very usable, is eating too much memory and is not searchable.

What I would expect from such a tool/website:

- Aggregate JavaDocs from different locations
- Direct access to types like Ctrl+T in Eclipse or similar
- Fulltext search
- Cross referencing between all the Java libraries I've chosen
- For a tool: offline support
- Speed

not mandatory:

- possibility to annotate things
- support for different versions of a library (+ diffing ?)
- IDE integration

Edit:

Thanks for your answers. I knew most of the sites but gave them another try. Here is my judgement:

- built-in Eclipse/IDE features

  - tightly integrated
  - offline/online support
- [<strike>javadoconline.com</strike>](http://www.javadoconline.com) (no longer maintained)

  - works
  - clean looks
  - finds matches in more than one version of the api and allows easy switching
  - simple but working
  - fast
- [<strike>jdocs</strike>](http://www.jdocs.com/) (offline)

  - seems very sophisticated
  - sometimes slow
  - some recent versions of libraries seem to be missing (Seam 2.0.0, Hibernate Validators) but it looks like you can add them yourself
  - IDE integration (not tested)
  - wiki style comments to each item
- [docjar.com](http://www.docjar.com/)

  - works
  - fast
  - cluttered UI
- [javadoc_isearch](http://www.teria.com/~koseki/tools/gm/javadoc_isearch/)

  - greasemonkey script for firefox which makes navigating javadocs easier
  - works smooth and perfectly

Comment: Except for the "cross-referencing", NetBeans does all the things from the first bullet list (and already did back in '08)

Comment: Related: [*Links to JDK documentation*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6987039/642706)

Answer (score 11):

JavaDoc jar can be unzipped directly. In theory any released javadocs can be downloaded and viewed offline.

1. download directly from maven repository. For example: http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/objectify/objectify/5.0.3/objectify-5.0.3-javadoc.jar
2. Now you get `objectify-5.0.3-javadoc.jar`, rename the file to `objectify-5.0.3-javadoc.zip`
3. use your favourite unzip tool to extract it, now you have a folder `objectify-5.0.3-javadoc`
4. double click `index.html` will open the index page on your default browser.

Answer (score 9):

If you use Eclipse, it offers support for Javadocs.  For example, hovering your mouse over a method call will display a tooltip showing you the Javadoc for that method.  Documentation for the core Java classes are supported out of the box.  However, if your project uses any additional libraries (JAR files), some configuration is required in order to plug their Javadocs into Eclipse.

1. Go to the "Java Build Path" section of your project properties.
2. Go to the "Libraries" tab and click the "plus" icon next to the JAR file.
3. Click "Javadoc location", then the "Edit..." button.

This will let you specify where the Javadocs for that JAR are located.  It will even let you specify a website URL, so you don't have to download the Javadocs yourself!

Comment: Thx for the exact explanation of how to do it. I knew it but there will probably be others who didn't.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote my own tool for this. Acording to my colleagues it is best they seen.

It indexes by lucene once, and run you small server on background, so yo browse javadocs (pydocs, perldocs..) like in browser. It allows also separate libraries per language so searchses like "biginteger" or simialr dont go wrong.

https://github.com/judovana/JavadocOfflineSearch/releases

Comment: Just spotted this... sorry to be a goose, but could you just tell me what I actually do when I've dlded your two jar files, i.e.  JavadocOfflineSearch_2.2.jar and  JavadocOfflineSearch.jar?

Comment: You need only the versined one. Tahs assembled with all depndencies.. I think that readme is quite descruiptive, isnt it? https://github.com/judovana/JavadocOfflineSearch/blob/master/README.md . It is on main page of the project.

Answer (score 2):

I use http://www.teria.com/~koseki/tools/gm/javadoc_isearch/ for FF. Lets me easily browse other libraries as well.

Comment: This looks a little bit outdated. Does it still work?

Comment: Yeah, I tested it and I really like it. It is fast and works as it should. Nice one.

Comment: For Firefox, you could simply type the following on the location bar: `jar:file://<path to your zip or jar archive>!/` . Don't forget the trailing slash. Credits: http://popqvarnstrom.blogspot.pt/2012/03/browsing-jarzip-files-eg-javadoc-in.html

Answer (score 2):

You can find Stanford University's JavaDoc [here](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs108/JavaDocFast.html).

Comment: I got a 404 for that, but there is also this: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs108/JavaDocFast.html

It just provides some nice quick links to doc for built-in Java classes

Comment: Both links dead

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse integrates well with Javadoc and has an HTML-like viewer for it.  You can attach source and javadoc to binaries that will show up when you select a class.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may be useful?

http://www.docjar.com/

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I know this one, but I don't like the search and it has no navigation bar or something like that. All together the design is not clean enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I've never had a problem with the built-in javadoc browsing tools offered by my IDE.

Currently, I use IntelliJ Idea -- Ctl-Q brings up the javadoc for the method under the cursor, with the hyperlinks to other parts of the documentation functional.

I would imagine NetBeans and Eclipse offer similar functionality.

Comment: +1 Exactly. Why bother with additional tools or websites, when it's easiest to read Javadocs right in the IDE where you mostly need them. (Get local copies of API docs (or sources) of external libs, to speed up accessing them.)

Comment: @Jonik "Why bother with additional tools": because not everybody is using them. e.g. the colleagues using Python and C++ should have access to the common interface documentation, which is coming from the Java side. -- Other people may (and will) be in circumstances different from yours.

Answer (score 1):

Hm... How about:

- http://edu.netbeans.org/quicktour/javadoc.html - NetBeans supports the Javadoc standard for Java documentation - both viewing it and generating it.
- http://globaldocs.zeevbelkin.com/ - This application allows to conveniently browse, over the Internet and local filesystem, multiple javadoc sets, using a single packages/classes hierarchy tree and a searchable index. The viewer supports local and remote docsets (the local docsets, packed to JAR/ZIP-files also are supported).

I prefer NetBeans as it get **JavaDoc** from **Maven** `~/.m2` directory automatically...

Comment: Interesting, however, I would prefer a pure web solution.

Comment: I use Netbeans and would like to use it for browsing general Javadocs without having to attach them to libraries and projects. Unfortunately your link about Netbeans appears to be outdated. The current Netbeans (version 7) doesn't seem to work that way.

Answer (score 1):

This plug in for Firefox and Chrome is useful for quickly finding package and class names, though it's not a full text search: https://code.google.com/p/javadoc-search-frame/

Comment: Interesting, didn't know this one. Thanks. I didn't try but what's probably missing is proper versioning of APIs (as it's only client-side).

Answer (score 0):

Doxygen (http://www.doxygen.nl/) might fit the bill.

EDIT: I may have misread your question, doxygen is a tool to generate documentation and models based off your code and javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is a best way to see the javadocs. Hovering the mouse on method or any declaration you will get automatically generated javadocs by eclipse.